# phpmyadmin only importing 48 records at a time

Tags: csv, import, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I'm importing a .csv file into a mysql database using phpmyadmin and the import function. The csv file is 118K big. Each time I try to import the file, the database accepts 48 records, then stops. The error is, "Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1306." (or whatever line). When I look at the line, there's nothing wrong with it. I cut off the top 48 records, make a csv file of the remaining records and try again. Again, the program stops after 48 records. I'm using WAMPserver64.

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
memory_limit = 128M
max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 1200
```

I've restarted services after each change to the php settings.

Does anyone have any input on how to fix this problem? I have 2,402 records left, and I'd really rather not input them 48 records at a time. Many thanks!

> Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1306. INSERT INTO hospital_addresses VALUES ('114008', 'COASTAL HARBOR TREATMENT CENTER', '1150 CORNELL AVE', 'SAVANNAH', 'GA', '31406')INSERT INTO hospital_addresses VALUES ('114010', 'PEACHFORD BEHAVIORAL HEALTH SYSTEM OF ATLANTA', '2151 PEACHFORD ROAD', 'ATLANTA', 'GA', '30338')

Here are the actual lines of data:

```
114008,COASTAL HARBOR TREATMENT CENTER,1150 CORNELL AVE,SAVANNAH,GA,31406 114010,PEACHFORD BEHAVIORAL HEALTH SYSTEM OF ATLANTA,2151 PEACHFORD ROAD,ATLANTA,GA,30338
```

Comment: Can you share the lines 1305 and 1306?... maybe a value in the line 1306 have an extra colon or missing a colon.

Comment: @esdebon: Sure - Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1306. INSERT INTO `hospital_addresses` VALUES ('114008', 'COASTAL HARBOR TREATMENT CENTER', '1150 CORNELL AVE', 'SAVANNAH', 'GA', '31406')INSERT INTO `hospital_addresses` VALUES ('114010', 'PEACHFORD BEHAVIORAL HEALTH SYSTEM OF ATLANTA', '2151 PEACHFORD ROAD', 'ATLANTA', 'GA', '30338')

Comment: Here are the actual lines of data: 114008,COASTAL HARBOR TREATMENT CENTER,1150 CORNELL AVE,SAVANNAH,GA,31406
114010,PEACHFORD BEHAVIORAL HEALTH SYSTEM OF ATLANTA,2151 PEACHFORD ROAD,ATLANTA,GA,30338

Comment: Maybe adding the name of the field in each insert (replacing in notepad )   INSERT INTO hospital_addresses (fieldName1, fieldName2, fieldName3, fieldName4, fieldName5, fieldName6)  VALUES ('114008', 'COASTAL HARBOR TREATMENT CENTER', '1150 CORNELL AVE', 'SAVANNAH', 'GA', '31406')

Comment: I can't do that -- this is the way the import function works. I guess I can write a php program to do this, but really, import is supposed to work.

Comment: All data in a row??, yo need a break line... the break line in windows is different that in unix (\n vs \r\n).  You have a long string, the field can hold it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a semi-colon separating the 2 SQL statements so it thinks its 1 statement with the wrong number of columns.

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO hospital_addresses VALUES ('114008', 'COASTAL HARBOR TREATMENT CENTER', '1150 CORNELL AVE', 'SAVANNAH', 'GA', '31406');
INSERT INTO hospital_addresses VALUES ('114010', 'PEACHFORD BEHAVIORAL HEALTH SYSTEM OF ATLANTA', '2151 PEACHFORD ROAD', 'ATLANTA', 'GA', '30338');
```

Are both rows of data in 1 row in your csv file? Your paste of the raw data implies that they ARE in 1 csv row. If so put the 2nd line of data onto a new row in your csv and try to import again.

Comment: They're on separate rows. For some reason, the program thinks they're one row. But even when I manually put in a break, the same thing happens.

Comment: I think using the format "CSV using LOAD DATA" instead of just "CSV" will be what I need.